# Alternate for data table(of .net) in java

Tags: java

A method in Java returns a schema. In .net, we use DataTable to get the data from the schema.
please tell me how to write the following code in Java:

```
            using (DataTable tbl = new DataTable())
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    sr.Write(r.DataSchema);
                    sr.Flush();
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(ms);
                    tbl.ReadXmlSchema(xtr);
                }
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    sr.Write(r.Data);
                    sr.Flush();
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(ms);
                    tbl.ReadXml(xtr);
                }
                foreach (DataRow dr in tbl.Rows)
                {
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=datatable+in+java

Comment: I din't find my answer there. :)